# Neo4j Browser – query lost on refresh

Tags: neo4j

Is there a way to recover the latest queries after refreshing the browser?

Steps to reproduce  (without this part the question is too short)  :)

- open a browser
- load "neo4j manager" page
- run several queries
- refresh the page

Comment: Do you mean the text of the queries, or the execution (possibly ongoing) and/or the results of the queries that were run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The history should be preserved such that you can cycle through the old queries with the up-arrow key - even across page reloads.